# How to do toast queue?

Tags: java, android, toast

I am working on Thread Queue. My aim is ensure not overlap that more than one toast at same time. Example Call toasts in onCreate,onStart,onResume states.

Firsty i create a class for toast helper that has toast queue with activity context. That queue execute a thread until queue has no items but this code is not work. But i dont know toast how to do wait a thread for toast ? if i use Thread.Sleep(4000) then main UI freezes

```
 public static void CreateToast(final ToastSettings toastSettings) {
        _toastQueue.add(toastSettings);
        if (_toastQueue.size() == 1) {
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (_toastQueue.size() != 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(_toastQueue.get(0).getContext(), _toastQueue.get(0).getMessage(), _toastQueue.get(0).isLong() ? Toast.LENGTH_LONG : Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        _toastQueue.remove(_toastQueue.get(0));
                        //thread sleep 4sec ??
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [postDelayed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
>   after the specified amount of time elapses.

for example:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 1500ms
  }
}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062798/handler-created-in-main-thread-acts-like-it-is-on-another-thread) answer for why it is behaving that way.

From my understanding if you don't want it to interrupt the main thread you will need to create the Handler in a seperate thread as the handler posts the runnable on the thread it was created on.

```
new Thread(()->{
    _toastQueue.add(toastSettings);
    if (_toastQueue.size() == 1) {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (_toastQueue.size() != 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(_toastQueue.get(0).getContext(), _toastQueue.get(0).getMessage(), _toastQueue.get(0).isLong() ? Toast.LENGTH_LONG : Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    _toastQueue.remove(_toastQueue.get(0));
                    //thread sleep 4sec ??
                }
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Wrapping the code you have in a separate thread and starting it should allow the toast to run independently from the main.

Comment: Interesting. Did you try the previous answer using postDelayed?

Comment: Just dis some reading in order to see the toast appear from a separate thread have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134683/android-toast-in-a-thread